# Limiting File Uploads with Spray

Tags: spray

I am building an API with Spray that accepts file uploads.
Typically the files will range in size from 100kb to 1mb.
Is it possible with spray to limit file uploads to below this size so that anything bigger is rejected?

Thanks

Comment: Look at the spray-can settings. https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-can/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L327 You can set `spray.can.server.request-chunk-aggregation-limit` which will make spray-can only try to collect incoming data up to the given limit and fails the connection otherwise.

Comment: Great, thanks. Can you post that as an answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the spray-can settings. https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-can/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L327 You can set `spray.can.server.request-chunk-aggregation-limit` which will make spray-can only try to collect incoming data up to the given limit and fails the connection otherwise.